# How to prevent jQuery UI autocomplete ESCAPE from closing Bootstrap modal?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete, modal-dialog

I have a Twitter Bootstrap modal, which has a field with jQuery UI Autocomplete in it. When the autocomplete suggestion menu is being displayed, user can press ESCAPE on their keyboard to close it. However, this also closes the Bootstrap modal, because it also listens to the ESCAPE key being pressed.

Is there a way to prevent the modal from being closed as long as the autocomplete suggestion menu is/was just being closed by ESCAPE key?

Note: I do not wish to completely disable escape key behaviour on the modal - only when the autocomplete menu is open and is closed via ESC.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to use the Bootstrap modal properties via JavaScript (Jquery), in this way:

assuming your modal's name is #MyModal use this to prevent to close with the keyboard

```
$('#myModal').modal({keyboard:false});
```

to see a live example I created one in the next example in [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/mJTUTOxH0J)!

Greetings & Happy Coding

Comment: Cool solution! I enjoyed my hackjob, but your answer is much more elegant!

Comment: Thanks, but I still want to close the modal with escape when the autocomplete suggestions are hidden.

Comment: Well @ragulka, I think you could set the property to false in the event when the autocomplete is shown **to avoid escape close** and when the autocomplete is hidden set the property to true **to allow escape close** you only need to control those two event (When autocomplete comes and when autocomplete goes)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Let's grab the escape key event and the modal hide event:

```
var isEscapeKey = false;

$('#myAutoCompleteTextBox').on('keydown',function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 27){
        isEscapeKey = true;
    } else{
        isEscapeKey = false;
    }
}).on('blur',function(){
    isEscapeKey = false;
});

$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    if (isEscapeKey){
        return false;
    }
});
```

Not tested, but in theory the `hide.bs.modal` event should be called before the modal is hidden and can be stopped here.